# JDBC DAO - any good reference implementation?

Tags: java, jdbc, dao

Can anyone point me to a well written DAO using JDBC, that covers all the exceptions a DAO should handle.

I looked at some samples at java.sun.com, their blue prints but there is a lot of theory and less code.

Looking through Spring DAO source code will be enlightening but that's way too complicated for me.

Answer (score 8):

[Spring  JdbcTemplate](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)  provides most plumbing you will need to implement a JDBC DAO.

Further Information at:

http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more simple implementation, you should take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/DAO.html).
However, a more complex sample is found [here](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer in some ORM tools - like Hibernate, TopLink, Apache Cayenne etc.
Sometimes ORM is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

An example can be found at http://daoexamples.sourceforge.net/. Looking through Google's code search, I found [this](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#y6YNM7BDLMc/trunk/Blog/src/java/es/blog/servicios/dao/DAO.java&q=dao%20lang:java&d=8) that has some DAOs. You may also want to do some research on generic DAOs, start [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html) and [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects).